# Typemock not showing any options in VS 2015

Tags: typemock-isolator

I've switched machines at work and Typemock worked fine on my old one but new one is having issues.  I installed typemock with the latest msi download.  Typemock shows as a menu option in VS but it only has three options (Options, Help, Try Full Version).  All of which are unresponsive when clicked.

When I go to the Tools menu in VS and go to the Typemock section it says that smart runner is enabled but I can't find any way to access it.  Right clicking on tests doesn't bring up anything in the context menu, the typemock menu only has the three options above and I can't find any windows related to smart runner.

If I go to the typemock configuration it says that smart runner is enabled and I have a license that is valid

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Typemock is not backwards compatible with all versions of VS.  Looks like VS 2015 Update 3 and VS 2017 work with the latest Typemock.  I didn't try them all, but at least those two work